# When i run npm start then give Node module error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/socks/build/common/helpers.js 9:15-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\Full stack web developer\node_modules\socks\build\common'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```